# UISearchController CONTAINS not finding partial results in Array of Dictionary

Tags: string, swift, nspredicate, contains, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to use a predicate to search an array of dictionary objects for a string value (from a searchController). I am not getting any partial string matches. I need to search through many key-values for a match, so I am doing it as written in the code below.

My problem is that if I search: "Orida"
I am not Finding: "Florida"

I believe I have the Predicate set correctly...

```
self.filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
let array = (self.airportData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
self.filteredData = array as! [Dictionary<String, String>]
```

It is working correctly if I type the exact matching string that appears in any Value of the dictionary, but not if I search for a partial match...

**This isn't a duplicate post** - all of the existing posts about this that I've found either aren't searching multiple values (like multiple key-values in my dictionary) or are using the contains() method on strings themselves.

**Update**

I have tried the answer suggested below using filter:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
let array = (self.airportData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

 self.filteredData = self.airportData.filter({(item: String) -> Bool in
 var stringMatch = item.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
 return stringMatch != nil ? true : false
```

I get the following error:

```
'(String) -> Bool' is not convertible to '([String : String]) -> Bool'
```

I'm confused about how to get this to handle the dictionary of strings properly.

Comment: What does look like a `NSDictionary` in `self.airportData`? Have they all have the same keys?

Comment: @larme They have different keys. Each dictionary is <String, String> though. About 5 keys at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.filteredData = self.airportData.filter({(item: String) -> Bool in
    var stringMatch = item.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
    return stringMatch != nil ? true : false
})
```

Try to do this using the swift `filter` method on your array instead.

Comment: Hmm.. I have an error right off the bat after copy pasting - '(String) -> Bool' is not convertible to ([String : String]) -> Bool'. I'm going to try and figure out what I need to cast or change to make your answer work to test it out.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize you were using a dictionary. You might have to cast it to an array like you did in your original code.

Comment: Where would the cast occur? I'm sorry if that is a dumb question - I'm new to swift and the closure throws me still. Would it be after the }) of the end of the closure and then just "as! [Dictionary<String, String>]" ?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the whole dictionary or just the keys or just the values?

Comment: The array contains dictionaries of airport data. I am looking to filter down the array to contain dictionaries that have entries that match the searchBar text

Comment: Are you searching by keys or values?

Comment: The keys don't matter to the search. Values are all I care about "finding".

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of advice from @pbush25, I was able to figure out an answer. It isn't exactly what I wanted, but it works. I was hoping to avoid specifying all the keys in the dictionary that I wanted to search the values of, but it ended up being the only way I could figure out to make it work. I would prefer to use the array.filter, but I couldn't figure out how to get that closure to cast as the right kind of array.

Functioning code:

```
let startCount = searchController.searchBar.text!.length
    delay(1) {
        if self.searchController.searchBar.text!.length >= 3 && self.searchController.searchBar.text!.length == startCount{
            self.view.addSubview(self.progressHud)
            self.appDel.backgroundThread(background: {
                self.filteredData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                let searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString

                self.filteredData = self.airportData.filter{
                    if let ident = $0["ident"] {
                        if ident.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    if let name  = $0["name"] {
                        if name.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    if let city = $0["municipality"] {
                        if city.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }
                },
                completion: {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.progressHud.removeFromSuperview()
                    }



            });
        }
    }
```